# What is causing this error in my code 'unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'int''

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create investment and also update the balance of the investment but I am getting this NoneType error. Below is my model and view code.

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    investment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.investment_id)



def create_investment_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        investment_form = InvestmentForm(request.POST)
        if investment_form.is_valid():
            investment = investment_form.save(commit=False)
            investment.balance += investment.amount
            investment.balance.save()
            investment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is successfull')
        else:
            messages.success(request, 'your investment is not successfull! Try again.')
    else:
        investment_form = InvestmentForm()
    context = {'investment_form': investment_form}
    return render(request, 'create-investment.html', context)
```

Comment: There should be a traceback with the error message that should tell you what caused the error.

Comment: Your `balance` field contains `None` value. You can either use `balance = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)` in your model or `investment.balance = (investment.balance or 0) + investement.amount` in your view. Also please note that `investment.balance.save()` is invalid (it is actually `int.save()` which does not exist), you need only `investement.save()`.

Comment: Most probably because `investment.balance` is None. Btw. `investment.balance.save()` doesn't make sense since you save the object with `investment.save()`.

Comment: balance = 0 fixed the error but I noticed the balance is not updating. What could be the problem?